# MongoDB performs slow query on sum() based on monthly groups

Tags: mongodb

This is What I tried so far on aggregated **query**:

```
db.getCollection('storage').aggregate([
  {
    "$match":  {
      "user_id":  2
    }
  },
  {
    "$project":  {
      "formattedDate":  {
        "$dateToString":  { "format":  "%Y-%m", "date":  "$created_on" }
      },
      "size":  "$size"
    }
  },
  { "$group":  {
    "_id"  :  "$formattedDate",
    "size" :  { "$sum":  "$size" }
  } }
])
```

This is the **result**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "2018-02",
    "size" : NumberLong(10860595386)
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2017-12",
    "size" : NumberLong(524288)
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "2018-01",
    "size" : NumberLong(21587971)
}
```

And this is the document **structure**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a59efedd006b9036159e708"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "is_transferred" : false,
    "is_active" : false,
    "process_id" : NumberLong(0),
    "ratio" : 0.000125759169459343,
    "type_id" : 201,
    "size" : NumberLong(1687911),
    "is_processed" : false,
    "created_on" : ISODate("2018-01-13T11:39:25.000Z"),
    "processed_on" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

And last, the explain result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "user_id" : 2.0
                },
                "fields" : {
                    "created_on" : 1,
                    "size" : 1,
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "data.storage",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "user_id" : {
                            "$eq" : 2.0
                        }
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "user_id" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "user_id",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "user_id" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "user_id" : [ 
                                    "[2.0, 2.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : true,
                "formattedDate" : {
                    "$dateToString" : {
                        "format" : "%Y-%m",
                        "date" : "$created_on"
                    }
                },
                "size" : "$size"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$formattedDate",
                "size" : {
                    "$sum" : "$size"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

The **problem**:

I can navigate and get all results in almost instantly like in `0,002sec`. However, when I specify user_id and sum them by grouping on each month, My result came in between 0,300s to 0,560s. I do similar tasks in one request and it becaomes more than a second to finish.

What I tried so far:

- I've added an index for user_id
- I've added an index for created_on
- I used more `$match` conditions. However, *This makes even worse*.

This collection have almost 200,000 documents in it currently and approximately 150,000 of them are belongs to `user_id = 2`

How can I minimize the response time for this query?

**Note**: MongoDB 3.4.10 used.

Answer (score 0):

Pratha,

try to add sort on "created_on" and "size" fields as the first stage in aggregation pipeline.

```html
db.getCollection('storage').aggregate([
  {
    "$sort":  {
      "created_on":  1, "size": 1
    }
  }, ....
```

Before that, add compound key index:
db.getCollection('storage').createIndex({created_on:1,size:1})

If you sort data before the $group stage, it will improve the efficiency of accumulation of the totals.

Note about sort aggregation stage:

The $sort stage has a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. By default, if the stage exceeds this limit, $sort will produce an error. To allow for the handling of large datasets, set the allowDiskUse option to true to enable $sort operations to write to temporary files.

P.S

get rid of match stage by userID  to test performance, or add userID to compound key also.

Comment: thank you for your reply. However, none of them worked for me. I exactly did what you suggested in order. Still same results. :/